# mysqli_query не работает последнее INSERT INTO в очереди

Tags: php, mysql

Вот есть такой код, не работает последнее условие $query_last, хоте выше, аналогичный код в $query-  работает, не пойму в чем проблема

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
    require 'connect_K.php';
    createMessage();
}
function createMessage(){
    global $connect;    
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $price_main = $_POST["price_main"];
    $date = $_POST["date"];
    $order_number = $_POST["order_number"];
    $query="INSERT INTO final(email,name,size,quantity,price)SELECT email,name,size,quantity,price FROM items_cart WHERE email like ('$email');";
    $query_del="DELETE FROM items_cart WHERE email like ('$email');";
    $query_upd="UPDATE final SET price_main='$price_main',order_number='$order_number',date='$date' WHERE email like ('$email');";
    /***** ВОТ тут проблемы *****/
    $query_last="INSERT INTO order(email,name,size,quantity,price,price_main,order_number,date)SELECT email,name,size,quantity,price,price_main,order_number,date FROM final WHERE email like ('$email');";
    /****************************/
    mysqli_query ($connect,$query)or die (mysqli_error($connect));
    mysqli_query ($connect,$query_del)or die (mysqli_error($connect));
    mysqli_query ($connect,$query_upd)or die (mysqli_error($connect));
    /***** ВОТ тут проблемы *****/
    mysqli_query ($connect,$query_last)or die (mysqli_error($connect));
    /****************************/
    mysqli_close($connect);
}
?>
```

Comment: Покажите лучше ошибку,так проще будет понять.

Comment: `аналогичный код в $query- работает, не пойму в чем проблема` - очень сомнительно. потому что у тебя в `insert` нет `values` и непонятно к чему относится `select`.... если второй запрос, то после `insert` не хватает еще точки с запятой

Comment: Для правильного ответа, требуется текст ошибки или описание того, какой ответ вы получаете (если нет ошибки). Что именно у вас не работает?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  "очень сомнительно. потому что у тебя в insert нет values".В MySQL есть такая  возможность   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan странная особенность. надо запомнить

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  Вы посмотрели этот пример? `INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (fld_id)
  SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id
  FROM tbl_temp1 WHERE tbl_temp1.fld_order_id > 100;`

Comment: Парень , с точки зрения MySQL синтаксиса вроде все в порядке.Я бы убрал точки с запятой с конца SQL строки.По моему их не надо ставить.Драйвер сам разберётся где закончилось выражение.И без выдаваемой ошибки вам трудно будет помочь

Comment: Что в ошибке пишет-то, скажешь?)) уверен что SELECT отрабатывает корректно?

Comment: @Romikromikromik может у вас в таблице `order` колонка `email` или какая то другая из того что ты задал в запросе задано как уникальная?

Comment: @Romikromikromik Второй вариант без показа вашей ошибки))))    `Может в двух таблицах у одинаковых колонок разные типы?`

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan просто забыл про insert-select))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Да у всех  бывает, иногда такая мелочь и не вспомнишь :)

Comment: Пишет, что проблема с синтаксисом. 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order(email,name,size)SELECT email,name,size,date FROM final WHERE email like ('' at line 1,   а на счет разных типов в одинаковых колонок, то везде VARCHAR ))

Comment: `order(email,name,size)SELECT email,name,size,date FROM final` - не кажется ли тебе, что это не похоже на то, что написано в вопросе? да и количество полей различается в сообщении об ошибке

Comment: @АлексейШиманский насчет количества полей ,это Postman как-то не корректно уведомил, поля совпадают по количеству и по типам.

Comment: order - это системно зарезервированное слово. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql